# finding base case for recursive function

Tags: recursion

I'm trying to practice recursion to count how many characters are between each pair of (),
not counting characters that are within other ()s. For example:

input:

```
(abc(ab(abc)cd)(()ab))
```

Would output:

```
Level 3: 3
Level 2: 4
Level 3: 0
Level 2: 2
Level 1: 3
```

"Level" Refers to the level of () nesting - Level 3 means the characters are within a pair within a pair within a pair.

What would be my base case? If I understand this correctly, the question I'm asking is, "how do I know when to stop making recursive calls and start resolving them?"

Since I didn't declare any variables in this post, pseudocode is okay.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I can help, but I won't solve your homework for you. Post some code or pseudo-code and we can go over it.

Comment: This is not homework. As a base case, I was thinking something like,

if (input[pos]=='(' && input[pos+1]==')')
        {
          total++
        }

but this shouldnt work for cases where the most inner parenthesis is not empty. ex: (ab) instead of ()

Comment: Perhaps adding some condition that checks if input[pos] until the end of the string does not contain another open parenthesis, count the number of characters until the next close parenthesis. I hope I'm being clear.

Comment: So there are four parts. You have an incoming string that starts with a "(", you have possibly some characters after the opening "(", you have the possibility of another opening "(", and lastly you have the rest of your level with a closing ")". One of those parts can be handed off to a recursive call if your method returns a string.

Comment: Or with a little more work you can do it with no return value.

Comment: This is obviously an old question, but I came across it and made an incomplete solution in Python which uses regex matching is used as a base case, would you like to see it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that your base case really depends upon your implementation and overall algorithmic approach, so your question is not really complete.

Nonetheless I devised something in Python which is not really perfect due to the work required during base case scenario (extra processing instead of simple return) but works well enough for me.

```
def findParenthesis(subject):
if "(" in subject:
    start = subject.index("(")
    #slice string to remove extraneous characters
    sub_str = subject[(start + 1):]
    if ")" in sub_str:
        #reverse string so that closing bracket can be found more easily
        rev_sub = sub_str[::-1]
        print("reverse substring is: " + rev_sub)
        #considering that a reverse array is being scanned +1 for negative indexing and make negative
        end = -(rev_sub.index(")") + 1)
        print("end bracket located at: " + str(end))
        return (start, end)
return False

def countEach(subject, levels, rec_count):
    bracket_inds = findParenthesis(subject)
    if not bracket_inds:
        #since the normal recursion procedure measures characters outside of the brackets the inside needs to be measured as well before return
        levels.append(0)
        for mid_char in subject:
            if mid_char.isalpha():
                levels[rec_count] += 1
        return levels
    else:
        #generate the next array index so there are no invalid reference errors
        levels.append(0)
        #rereference for readability
        start, end = bracket_inds
        for pre_char in subject[:start]:
            #conditional for only finding alphabetic characters, not necessarily required
            if pre_char.isalpha():
                levels[rec_count] += 1
        for pst_char in subject[end:]:
            if pst_char.isalpha():
                levels[rec_count] +=1

        return countEach(subject[ (start + 1) : end ], levels, (rec_count + 1))

sample = "(abc(ab(abc)cd)(()ab))"

arr_out = []
rec_count = 0

print(countEach(sample, arr_out, rec_count))
```

Originally instead of implementing 'findParenthesis()' I used a regex something along the lines of `"[\w\(\)]*\(([\w\(\)]+)\)[\w\(\)]*"` passed in as argument 'query' to countEach() and match.group(0) would be the argument 'subject' to the next recursive call, thus when `[compiled_regex].search(subject)` returned None that would be the base case.

As you can see however the expression is not very readable, so I it's still possible to do but would have a similar overall complexity